# Showing every number of form $0.a_1a_2 \dots $ where $a_n \in \{0, 2 \}$ lie in cantor set.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, real-numbers, number-systems, cantor-set

> How do I show that every number of  form $0.a_1a_2 \dots $ where $a_n  \in \{0, 2 \}$ lies in Cantor set?

From other posts, it's clear to me that $k$-th iteration, in ternary representation, removes interval with $1$ on $k$-th position i.e. $(0.a_1 \dots a_{k-1} 1 , 0.a_1 \dots a_{k-1} 1\bar 2)$. Could it be possible to show (inductively) that every sequence of $0.a_1a_2 \dots $ where $a_n  \in \{0, 2 \}$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$ lies in cantor set?

Comment: I am not sure if such sequence always lie in Cantor set. I am just guessing.

Comment: Check a number of that form remains in each step of the construction.

Comment: Let $x$ be such number which consists of sequence of 0 and 2. Suppose $x \in I_k$ where $I_k$ consists of sequences of 0 and 2 upto k position. Then $I_{1,k+1}$ and $I_{2,k+1}$ consists of sequence of 0 and 2 up to $k+2$ position. Since $x$ consists of 0 and 2, it must lie in either of interval as it's bigger than smaller endpoint and less than larger endpoint. Does that work?

Comment: Yes, your argument seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

That depends a bit on how you define the Cantor set. There are at least three(*) different equivalent definitions of which using ternary expansion is one of them. To see that they are equivalent we can reformulate them so they all will produce a sequence of sets and the Cantor set being the intersection of these sets - you then prove the equivalence by showing that the definitions produce identical sequence of sets.

To reformulate the definition using ternary expansion you define:

$$C_n = \left\{\sum c_j3^{-j}\right\}$$

where $c_j \in \{0,2\}$ if $j\le n$ and $c_j\in \{0,1,2\}$ if $j\gt n$. You then by induction show that $C_j$ is the same sequence of sets as for the other definitions. To complete the proof you show that $\bigcap C_j$ is the set of numbers with ternary expansion of only $0$s and $2$s.

(*) The other two are those which start with the unit interval and either subsequently removing the mid thirds or replace the set with two copies of size $1/3$ of the previous.